# Filter array with Model.find() Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model where one of the fields is an array of dates and I need to query the collection to find any document that has a date between the 7 past days inside that array, but when I try to use $gt or $gte it doesn't return me the documents, even if exists (I have checked if the documents exist).

[Here it is an example of the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtJOu.png)

It shouldn't return me objects with more than 7 days past.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
const { subDays } = require("date-fns");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Journey = require("./models/Journey");
const url = "my-db-url";

mongoose.set("useNewUrlParser", true);
mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);

mongoose.connect(url, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log("Mongoose connected");
});

Journey.find({
  hospital: "5e6fc0d98db5810012aeb8fe",
  active: false,
  timestampStart: {
    $gte: subDays(new Date(), 7)
  }
})
  .lean()
  .exec((err, journeys) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(journeys[0]);
  });
```

The Journey model:

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const JourneySchema = new Schema(
  {
    tag: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "Tag",
    },
    patient: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "Patient",
    },
    hospital: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "Hospital",
    },
    department: {
      type: [String],
      required: true,
    },
    timestampStart: {
      type: [Date],
      required: true,
    },
    timestampEnd: {
      type: [Date],
      required: true,
    },
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
    rssi: {
      type: [String],
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = model("Journey", JourneySchema);
```

Can anyone help me build this filter?

Comment: The `$gte` filter you have seems like it should work with dates.  I did notice that the sample document does not contain a field named `active`.  Try filtering for `active: {$ne: true}` instead of `active: false`, that way it will also match when the active field is missing

Comment: NIce, thanks for the suggestion. The active field is missing because I've removed it using the select function, but when I posted here I forgot to add it to the query code.

Answer (score 1):

The date query seems to working just fine. I think the problem would be with the hospital, and active key. In the sample object that you have provided, both are missing. Can you check it by removing those keys in the query, or by adding them in the collection.

Comment: Oh, they're missing because I've excluded it with the select function but forgot to add the query code here, but I've found the error, it was on the database, some dates were wrong. Anyway, thanks for the help!